# Control the page user is directed to once they sign into their account

Tags: meteor, flow-router

I'm currently using Flow Router to manage page loads. On sign-in I would like to check if the users account has been 'activated by admin' and direct them to one of two pages.

Scenario 1 - User account **not active**, send user to profile.html
Scenario 2 - User account **active**, send user to blog.html

I can't find any examples only, could someone please tell me how to do it or direct me to an example I could follow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use Accounts.validateLoginAttempt hook on server side like this.

```
Accounts.validateLoginAttempt(function(attempt) {

    if( ! attempt.user || ! attempt.user.profile.status.isActive){
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
});
```

And this is how you can redirect to user if not active on client side.

```
Meteor.loginWithPassword(user, password, function( err, res ){
    if(err){
        //redirect to login or other route
    } else {
       //redirect to dashboard
    }
});
```

Comment: OK, Not sure I follow. When I add this code it just blocks the user from being able to login to their account if attempt.user.profile.status.isActive is false. How do I integrate this with flow router? I'm a noob sorry.

Comment: You just have to replace attempt.user.profile.status.isActive with your status flag in user schema. I hope that make your doubt clear.

Comment: Sorry, I diddo that. `if( ! attempt.user || ! attempt.user.accountStatus)` but what do I do then?

Comment: Can you please check in db that accountStatus filed exist in db or not.

Comment: You can access the db using "mongo -h localhost:3001" in case you app running on 3000.

Comment: yes `( ! attempt.user || ! attempt.user.accountStatus.isUserAccountActive)`

Comment: This just locks the user out if their account isn't active. How do I use it to direct them to specific pages

Comment: Updated my Answer please check.